# SPSS: Compute variable based on COUNT of different values

Tags: count, spss

I've simplified this for an example of what I'm trying to do. I have 3 different variables with values ranging from 1 to 5:

[image]

I'd need to compute a new variable that counts the appearance of each of the values across all cases and all 3 variables. The goal is to be able to show how many times each value appears (eg. 5 appears 3 times) and I've been told that can be achieved with the Compute variable method, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Example .sav file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CwfU7_C40VUyoBdChCRYSx8Mk6rGA0Vq), if it helps. Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to create 5 new variables, each containing the number of occurrences of a specific value in each row. Then to get the complete count you just sum these variables:

```
do repeat vr=occ1 to occ5/vl=1 to 5.
   compute vr=sum(Mention1=vl, Mention2=vl, Mention3=vl).
end repeat.
exe.
```

Now you have the 5 new variables (eg. var `occ1` has the count of the occurrences of the number 1 in each row). There are a few ways to get the complete total.
To simply get it in the output window:

```
descriptives occ1 to occ5/statistics=sum.
```

But in your question you mentioned adding the counts to the actual dataset. This can be done using the `aggregate` command:

```
aggregate /out=* mode=addvariables /break= /TotOcc1 to TotOcc5=sum(occ1 to occ5).
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to access your .sav file from this computer, but this is the solution I came up with for your example data:

```
*Dataset1 should equal your original dataset name.
DATASET ACTIVATE Dataset1.

*This creates a table with the counts of each occurance of 1 through 5.
FREQUENCIES VARS MENTION1 MENTION2 MENTION3.
EXECUTE.

*This translates the frequencies table to a dataset called 'freqtbl'.
DATASET DECLARE freqtbl.
OMS Select Tables
/IF SUBTYPES =['Frequencies']
/DESTINATION format = sav outfile=freqtbl.
freq vars= MENTION1 MENTION2 MENTION3.
OMSEND.

*This will make sure you are referencing the new dataset you created: 'freqtbl'.
*The ALTER TYPE statement turns VAR2, which is the occurances of 1 through 5, back into a numeric variable.
DATASET ACTIVATE freqtbl.
ALTER TYPE VAR2 (F1.0).

*This is a simple if/then statement across all of your values.
IF VAR2 = 1 FREQ_1 = SUM(FREQUENCY).
IF VAR2 = 2 FREQ_2 = SUM(FREQUENCY).
IF VAR2 = 3 FREQ_3 = SUM(FREQUENCY).
IF VAR2 = 4 FREQ_4 = SUM(FREQUENCY).
IF VAR2 = 5 FREQ_5 = SUM(FREQUENCY).
EXECUTE.

*This cleans up your dataset and computes a dummy variable to aggregate counts.
DELETE VARIABLES COMMAND_ TO CumulativePercent.
COMPUTE DUMMY = 1.
EXECUTE.

*This aggregates your frequency columns to count all occurances of 1 through 5.
AGGREGATE 
    /OUTFILE = *
    MODE = ADDVARIABLES
    /BREAK DUMMY
    /COUNT_1 = SUM(FREQ_1)
    /COUNT_2 = SUM(FREQ_2)
    /COUNT_3 = SUM(FREQ_3)
    /COUNT_4 = SUM(FREQ_4)
    /COUNT_5 = SUM(FREQ_5).
EXECUTE.
```